# How can I apply NOW() along with Exposed DAO

Tags: kotlin-exposed

I have such a table.

```
object AsdTable : IntIdTable("asd") {
    val created_date = timestamp("created_date")
    val code = varchar("code", 64)
}
```

And I'd like to build sql insert statement like `INSERT INTO asd(created_date, code) VALUES(NOW(), ??)`
Kotlin code is

```
transaction {
  AsdEntity.new {
    createdDate = ?
    code = "oook"
  }
}
```

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work via `defaultExpression`:

```
object AsdTable : IntIdTable("asd") {
    val created_date = timestamp("created_date").defaultExpression(CurrentTimestamp())
    val code = varchar("code", 64)
}

transaction {
  AsdEntity.new {
    code = "OK"
  }
}
```

NOW() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() is generated within INSERT statement.